# Getting occasional error getting user from Google PlusDomains

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an app that make the following call successfully for 99% of the users:

```
var profile = PlusDomains.People.get(userId);
```

However, some users consistently have the following error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: Not Found at fetchPhoto
```

When I manually go to plus.google.com/(userId) the user is there so I know the userId is good.  Has anyone seen this or has any idea why it is (rarely) happening?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: Can you try executing the command 
var profile = PlusDomains.People.get(userId); and replacing "userId" with the actual userID of the data causing error and see what happens?

Comment: Tried hardcoding it like this, same error:  **var profile = PlusDomains.People.get(107073770869240411525);**

Comment: compare it to the working user IDs and check for the difference.

Comment: That's the point, there is no discernable difference.  Both have valid G+ accounts and valid pictures.  I suspect a bug.

Comment: this is interesting. Can you give us sample of a valid data and data that's causing an error?

Comment: Well, it is just a handful of internal users in our domain.  I have looked at them but there does not seem to be any commonality in why it  is failing for them and not the vast majority of others.